# Read only Strings from a file using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am creating a method that creates a file that contains the Strings from another file that can have anything( ints, doubles... ). I am using another method that returns true if the input its a String.

```
public static void buscarFichero(String ftx){
    File f = new File(ftx);
    Scanner s = null;
    PrintWriter p = null;
    try{
        s = new Scanner(f).useLocale(Locale.US);
        p = new PrintWriter(ftx + "_nuevo");
        while(s.hasNextLine()){
            String aux = s.nextLine();
            if(esString(aux) == true){
                String b = aux.trim();
                p.println(b);
            }
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
    finally{
        if(s != null){ s.close(); }
        if(p != null){ p.close(); }
    }
}
public static boolean esString(String x){
    if(x.equals(x.toString())){ return true;}
    else{ return false; }
}
```

I know I am using and auxiliar that it is always making the nextLine into a String, but I have not the knowledge to fix it. I want to get rid of everything that it is not a String

Comment: What do you mean you 'have no idea of how to make it'? How to make what? Your esString method does not really do anything, because everything you pass in is already a string. This method will always either return true or throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: Just FYI, nextLine() will always return a String.

Comment: You can collect any data from the file as a String. "10" is a String storing the characters '1' and '0'. Are you trying to get rid of numbers present in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you read from a file is going to technically be a String. I believe that what you are trying to accomplish is to distinguish whether or not a particular String contains only letters. If this is true then what you need to do is compare the character codes. In this example I check if the character is not a character from a-z or A-Z. If so, then it is not a word.

```
private static boolean isWord(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if ((c < 'A' || c > 'Z') && (c < 'a' || c > 'z')) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```